PSPACE is closed under polynomial time reductions?
A class $C$ is closed under polynomial time reductions if for every two languages $_1
, _2$
such that $_1 \leq_{} _2$ and $_2 \in C$, it holds that $_1 \in C$.
My question is how to
prove that PSPACE is closed under polynomial time reductions?

My motivation:
PSPACE is closed under polynomial-time reductions because any language  $L_1 \leq_p L_2$  means  $L_1$  can be decided by a polynomial-time reduction to  $L_2$ , and since  $L_2 \in \text{PSPACE}$ ,  $L_1$  can also be decided in PSPACE by simulating both the reduction and the PSPACE algorithm for  $L_2$ . PSPACE algorithms can simulate polynomial-time computations with space efficiency.
How to proceed from here? This question asked here before with no answer.

You pretty much wrote the whole thing. Given input $x$, simulate the reduction, it's output is still of polynomial size in $x$, so you can now run a PSPACE machine for $L_2$. Correctness is immediate by the definition of a reduction.
